# JavaScript function multiple calling

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Source code:

```
function CreateArray(length) {
    var array1 = [];
    for (var k = 0, t = length; k < t; k++) {
        array1.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
    };
    return array1;
var array = CreateArray(100,500,1000) // works only for 100


console.time("insertionSort")

function insertionSort(array) {
    var countOuter = 0;
    var countInner = 0;
    var countSwap = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        countOuter++;
        var temp = array[i];
        var j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && array[j] > temp) {
            countInner++;
            countSwap++;
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1] = temp;
    }

    console.log('outer:', countOuter, 'inner:', countInner, 'swap:', countSwap);
    return array;
}
console.timeEnd("insertionSort")

insertionSort(array.slice());
```

with this last calling I want to check 100,500,1000,5000 and other different lengths. Any ideas?

I want that the last calling will work for any lengths of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `CreateArray` to create multiple arrays at once, and then you need `insertionSort` to be able to process multiple arrays at once - or, even better, call *another* function (once) that calls `insertionSort` for each array:

```js
const CreateArray = (...lengths) => lengths.map(length => (
  Array.from({ length }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000000))
));

function insertionSort(array) {
  var countOuter = 0;
  var countInner = 0;
  var countSwap = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    countOuter++;
    var temp = array[i];
    var j = i - 1;
    while (j >= 0 && array[j] > temp) {
      countInner++;
      countSwap++;
      array[j + 1] = array[j];
      j--;
    }
    array[j + 1] = temp;
  }
  console.log('outer:', countOuter, 'inner:', countInner, 'swap:', countSwap);
}
const insertionSortMultipleArrays = (arrs) => {
  arrs.forEach(arr => {
    console.time("insertionSort");
    insertionSort(arr);
    console.timeEnd("insertionSort");
  });
};
  
const arrays = CreateArray(100,500,1000,5000);
insertionSortMultipleArrays(arrays);
```

Comment: nice solution :-)

Comment: @rollback Being pretty functional, It looks very readable to me (except for the `insertionSort` part, which is nearly by definition a little bit convoluted), what were you thinking of?

Comment: ok, i understood a little bit, but what about already sorted array:

function Sorted(a, b) { 
    if (a > b) return 1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
}
var array8 = [];
for (var k= 0, t=100; k<t; k++){
    array8.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 3000000))
};
array8.sort(Sorted);

how to add this array with the any lenght(100,500,1000) to this algorithm?

Comment: Same way `insertionSort` was turned into `insertionSortMultipleArrays` - have another function call it multiple times (or turn your sort function into one that iterates over and sorts multiple arrays, rather than just a single one)